# Migration of On-Prem to Azure

Tags: azure

I have a web application that is running on my localhost and i want to use azure app service or azure vm to launch it online. which is the best choice?

Solution to host webapplication

Answer (score 0):

**There are ways to deploy your application to Azure Cloud.**

**Method 1** :  **Azure App Service** is fully managed platform for deploying application and scaling apps. it has built-in web hosting feature and supports multiple languages and frameworks.

Please follow the steps to deploy application to **App Service**.

1.Create sample web application using **Visual Studio** application.

[image]

2. Create a new project

[image]

3. Right click on created application and choose **Publish**

> Note: Before publish application to Azure, login to visual studio with Azure Account.

[image]

5. Select target-**Azure** Cloud.

[image]

5.Select target platform **windows** or **Linux**.

[image]

6. Click on **App Service (Windows)** > **Create new (window)**" in **App Service (Windows)** >Create new.

[image]

7. Select your **subscription, resource group & hosting plan**.

[image]

8. Check the **Application deployment** status in visual studio account.

[image]

9.Test the application with **Azure App service URL** once deploy the application to Azure app service.

**Go to Azure Portal > Azure App Service > overview > Url**.

[image]

10. Application working with **App service Url**

[image]

**Method** 2: **Azure VM**

To deploy an application in an **Azure VM** with **IIS**, you can follow below steps:

1. Create an Azure VM with required configuration such as the operating system and size.

**Azure Portal > Create > Select Server OS.**

[image]

2.Use **RDP** to connect to the Azure VM.

[image]

3. You can use **FTP** to upload your code to the **Azure VM**.
4. Now, open the **IIS Manager** and create a new website in that **IIS**.
5. After that, you can configure the website to point to the location of your application code on the **VM**.
6. Finally, test your application.